# Sets and combinatorial counting

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math

> There is $35$ sets each has $27$ elements. Fore every $3$ sets there is exactly one element that belongs them. Prove that there exist exactly one element that belongs all of the $35$ sets.

It is easy to show that $2$ elements (or more) cannot be in all sets. But I do not know why there is at least one element which belongs all sets. Please ,help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take one of those sets $A_1= \{1,2,...,27\}$.  So for each pair of sets $B,C\ne A_1$ they have one element in common. Since we have ${34\choose 2} = 17\cdot 33 = 561$ pairs not involving $A_1$ means that at least one element from $A_1$, say $1$, is in at least $21$ pairs. So $1$ is in at least $7+1$ sets: $A_1,A_2,...A_8$.

Now suppose there is $B$ that does not contain $1$. Then each triple $\{B,A_i,A_j\}$ contains common element, which is not $1$ but it is in $B$. Since the number of all such triples is 28 and $B$ has only 27 elements, we see that two triples, say $\{B,A_i,A_j\}$ and $\{B,A_k,A_l\}$ (it can be $i=k$, etc... but at least three of $A_i,A_j,A_k,A_l$ are different) must have the same element in common, say $b$. But then some three from $A_i,A_j,A_k,A_l$ have two common elements, namely $1$ and $b$.

A contradiction.